# Create an array from parts of file names with python

Tags: python, arrays, filesystems

I have a directory of csv files for instance

`c:\data`

will contain the following files

`ext-FLA-1.csv`

`ext-KDY-1.csv`

`etx-EIR-1.csv`

I would like to extract an array of only the capital letters of each file.

```
files = glob.glob('c:\\data/*.csv')
```

Will give me an array of all the csv files. However I would like the files array to only contain

```
files = ['FLA','KDY','EIR']
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, what Sardorbek Imomaliev means is that this is not a free coding service and that you are expected to show some effort. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can use regexp for this:

```
import re
import os
files = [os.path.abspath(f) for f in os.listdir('c:\\data') if re.search(r'[A-Z]+.*\.csv$', f)]
```

or if you need only capital letters:

```
import re
import os
files = [re.findall(r'[A-Z]+', f)[0] for f in os.listdir('c:\\data') if re.search(r'.csv$', f)]
```